# Why is my XML Array not able to be called?

Tags: php, xml, arrays

I'm trying to get call an XML array using PHP, but for whatever reason, it is not providing results properly. The XML looks like this as a simpleXMLElement.

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [copyright] => All data copyright 2012.
        )

```
[route] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [@attributes] => Array
            (
                [tag] => 385
                [title] => 385-Sheppard East
                [color] => ff0000
                [oppositeColor] => ffffff
                [latMin] => 43.7614499
                [latMax] => 43.8091799
                [lonMin] => -79.4111
                [lonMax] => -79.17073
            )

        [stop] => Array
            (
                [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [tag] => 14798
                                [title] => Sheppard Ave East At Yonge St (Yonge Station)
                                [lat] => 43.7614499
                                [lon] => -79.4111
                                [stopId] => 15028
                            )

                    )
              [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [@attributes] => Array
                            (
                                [tag] => 4024
                                [title] => Sheppard Ave East At Doris Ave
                                [lat] => 43.7619499
                                [lon] => -79.40842
                                [stopId] => 13563
                            )

                    )
```

There are several parts to the stop array. My code looks like this:

```
$url = "this_url";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
$route_array = $xml->route->stop;
```

When I print the $route_array, it only shows 1 record from the stops. Do I need to run this through a loop? Normally when I do this in JSON, it works fine. I'd like to get everything in the stop array only.

Thanks in advance to all of you experts out there helping out a beginner like myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `print_r` on SimpleXML elements does not always give you the full picture. Your elements are there but aren't shown.

`$xml->route->stop` is an array of `<stop>` tags within `<route>`. So if you want to loop through each stop tag then:

```
foreach($xml->route->stop as $stop)
{
    echo (string)$stop; // prints the value of the <stop> tag
}
```

In the loop, `$stop` is a SimpleXML element, so in order to print its value you can cast the whole element as a string using the `(string)` syntax. You can still access attributes and other SimpleXML element properties.

If you know which `<stop>` element you want to target, then you can get it directly:

```
echo (string)$xml->route->stop[1]; // prints the second <stop> value
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I just did! Any ideas on if there is a better way to view the XML instead of the Print_R?

Comment: As far as I know there's no official note but to debug I use echo on the individual elements instead of print_r the entire object. Another option is to use the `saveXML()` method to view the actual XML.

Comment: I'll give the saveXML() function a try. Thanks!